# How to make html navigation bar simple without server side programming

Tags: css, html

I have four menus in my website.

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='home.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='about.html'><span>About</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='support.html'><span>Support</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='contact.html'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

every html file has same contents and I put `class='active'` differently.

But If I have adding more menu, or If I want to change the file name `home.html`to`index.html`. I need to open all files and modify it. This is not a good I think.

What is good solution in general?

thanks in advance.

**updates**

I didn't mention it. my fault. I don't want to use a programming language. I just wanted to know any easy way to do it by using html/css.

Comment: Move on from basic HTML to asp.net, jsp, php etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really dont want to use any server side language like php, asp etc. You can use javascript as it is what you are asking I think.
It wont be possible with just html markup.

```
document.write("<div id=\"menu\">");
document.write("<ul>");
document.write("<li class='active'><a href='home.html'><span>Home<\/span><\/a><\/li>");
document.write("<li><a href='about.html'><span>About<\/span><\/a><\/li>");
document.write("<li><a href='support.html'><span>Support<\/span><\/a><\/li>");
document.write("<li><a href='contact.html'><span>Contact<\/span><\/a><\/li>");
document.write("<\/ul>");
document.write("<\/div>");
```

Place all of those in a js file perhaps menu.js and then in each html page place a script tag to call it.

```
<script src="menu.js"></script>
```

Atleast that way you can change it one place without using serverside scripts.
May or may not be ideal however hopefully it answers your question.

Here are a couple of places that may help you if you require more info.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp

http://www.accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/html-javascript-convertor/

Use last one to create the document.write for you easily.

You should also use conditions to determine which page is currently active to place your active class.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a lot of server-side logic, you could use a [static site generator](http://staticsitegenerators.net).

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce an embedded programming language. You can do this either at runtime or during a build process. Many languages have tools for doing so:

- [PHP](http://www.php.net/)
- Java: [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages)
- VB/C#: [ASP](http://www.asp.net/)
- Ruby: [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html)
- Python: [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)
- JavaScript: [Jupiter's EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/), [Visionmedia's EJS](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs)

Here's an example that uses PHP:

```
<!-- index.php, contact.php, whatever.php -->
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <!-- We include a reference to the file with the header -->
 <?php include("header.php"); ?>
 <p>Welcome to the home page!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In the file that specifies your header, you'll need to add a helper function that will  determine when to set the class to "current". Here's a rough example:

```
<!-- header.php -->

<?php
  // Prints "active" if the provided page name matches the extensionless basename
  // of the current script. For example, if the current file is index.php or
  // index.html, the function will echo 'current' for when $page_name = index
  function active_page_class($page_name) {
    $filename = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $filename_without_ext = substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '.'));
    if ($filename_without_ext == $page_name) echo 'active';
  }
?>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="<?php active_page_class('index') ?>">
      <a href="index.html"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php active_page_class('contact') ?>">
      <a href="contact.html"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now, instead of writing the current page class helper in PHP, you could alternatively do it with JavaScript/jQuery. Here's an jQuery example:

```
$(function() {
  $('#menu li').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    if (href === window.location.pathname) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

You can similarly append the menu bar in every page using JavaScript instead of using a server side script.

Note that using a language like PHP will require that you either host the site on a server that supports the language or build the files locally before publishing them.

You can easily build any PHP page using the command-line tool:

```
php index.php > index.html
```

You could also consider using a [static site generator](http://staticsitegenerators.net/). Many of them provide many more nifty features that you might find useful.

Comment: how does EJS compare to Node.js ?

Comment: You can't compare EJS to NodeJs: EJS is a templating language whereas NodeJS is a runtime platform.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest use PHP or some php-based framework and include parts of pages you'd like to display.

Example:

file1.php

```
<?php

$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ....";

?>
```

file2.php

```
<?php
include file1.php;

<h1>Welcome!</h1>
echo "$text";

?>
```

For more examples try to look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp), w3schools has quite easy tutorials for php stuff.